# How to Import System.ServiceProcess namespace into WPF project? Not showing in CodeSense

Tags: wpf, vb.net, import

how can I import the `System.ServiceProcess` namespace into a WPF project in VB.NET (not C#)? The `ServiceController` object is not in the toolbox in VS2008 and I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas? If that particular namespace cannot be imported into WPF projects, could somebody suggest another way of controlling windows services from a WPF application? I know this framework is focused more on multimedia apps, but would really like to switch over some of my tools to WPF.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

You need to add a reference to `System.ServiceProcess.dll`.

The confusing thing is that this assembly is not in `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework`. It should be be in the GAC; however, it might not show in the list of assemblies. You can browse to `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` and reference it from there.

Comment: Yeah, I found that DLL, but guess I´ll have to figure out how to reference a single file. I tried to add it to the Customize ToolBox window but it goes directly into the .Net Framework tab. Thanks a lot for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean you want to add a project reference, rather than specifically adding it into a XAML file.

You will need to add a reference to the appropriate DLL, but it might be hidden from you if you aren't targeting the correct framework version -- make sure your project properties say you are targeting 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I used VS2017, I searched for `System.ServiceProcess` in NuGet manager (Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...)

Install it for the required projects and that is it.

[image]